# Connect to Ubuntu machine on local network using Screen Sharing, screen doesn't update

Tags: remote-desktop, unix, screen-sharing

I'm trying to connect to my Ubuntu desktop from my Mac laptop (10.6.6). The linux machine shows up fine in my network list, and when I connect to it, Screen Sharing prompts me for a password (which is how I have the Ubuntu machine configured).

I finish connected and I'm presented with a view of the desktop in Ubuntu. From the laptop it appears I can't select or do anything. As it turns out, the mouse interaction ***is*** working. Its just that the the view itself is frozen. I verified this by having the machines side-by-side. The mouse events are being and as a result I can't manipulate the contents of the Ubuntu screen; its just that the screen updates either aren't being sent back to the laptop or they are but Screen Sharing isn't updating.

Anyone else run into issues connecting to Ubuntu machines from Screen Sharing? It seems like I have it 99% the way there, just needing to resolve the refresh issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried opening the Screen Sharing app (`/System/Library/CoreServices/`) and typing in the `vnc://` address to the Ubuntu machine?

You can also try changing the Screen Sharing prefs. With the Screen Sharing app open, go to Screen Sharing -> Preferences and changing settings to the ones that say `faster`?

Hope this helps.